# PHP version exposed on blogoverflow

Tags: feature-request, security, blog-overflow

The HTTP response header for Blog Overflow does not give a `Server:` string at all, assumably for (slight) security benefit. However, it *does* include an `X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3` header, and also supports [the PHP easter egg URLs](http://blogoverflow.com/?=PHPB8B5F2A0-3C92-11d3-A3A9-4C7B08C10000). You probably want to set [`expose_php`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.expose-php) to false.

Comment: Even my bank does not hide that information... (Seam Framework, IBM HTTP Server, Windows 2003.)

Comment: @Arjan: When it comes to security, you probably want to do everything exactly *opposite* of most banks.

Comment: @TheEstablishment nonsense, I look forward to SO having a max length limit on passwords

Comment: Jokes aside, I thought we were done hiding stuff that like that. Why not give the PHP community some credits? Headers like `X-Powered-By` and `Generator` have their merits, and they are the least intrusive for the website owner.

Comment: I seem to be missing the point here -- how exactly is this a security issue? What would be the point of hiding it?

Comment: @balpha Someone decided to hide the the Apache name/version/platform. They probably did this to make targeting vulnerabilities in a particular apache version harder. So, its inconsistent (and looks like a mistake) to not hide the PHP one (especially since PHP likely has far more vulnerabilities than Apache).

Comment: @derobert we did no special config to hide those, its probably a rhel/centos defaut for the httpd package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Security by obscurity is a broken concept. Attackers don't waste time with a version check anyway – they just send their malicious code with the first request.

Hiding the PHP version would not make the blog more secure. You save some bytes during the request, but that's all.

Comment: We have people trying to exploit Apache and PHP issues *on Stack Overflow* all the time, which runs on IIS and ASP.NET MVC. Talk about not wasting time with a version check :)